# Accessing static inner class in Java peculiar bhavior - Why?

Tags: java, static, inner-classes

To my understanding following code should not `compile` as we can not change enclosing `class` parameters when extending non `static` inner `classes`.

However, This code is working fine.

```
class A<T0, T1> {
    class B {
        T0 t0;
        T1 t1;
    }

    class C extends A<T1, T0>.B {
        T0 t00 = t1;
        T1 t11 = t0;
    }
}
```

Please help me understand why it is behaving like this or my understanding is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> code should not compile as we can not change enclosing class
>   parameters

For one, you haven't changed the existing *parameters*, you have just modified the type bound to the class while inheriting.

And two, the type bound that you've changed is nothing but reversed while interpreting the parameters of the inner class `C` as compared to the parent class `B` both of which are inferred from the bound of `A<T, R>`.